# android 5.1 - onActivityResult returning nullpointerexception by taking photo from camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop, android-camera-intent

I get this error when I take an image using camera :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {ir.aflak.niaz/ir.aflak.niaz.NewAdd2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3539)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

It works fine on pre lolipop android . this is my code :

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        OutputURI = data.getData();
        Bitmap thePic = null;
        try {
            thePic = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(NewAdd2.this.getContentResolver(), OutputURI);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            Log.v("this", e1.getMessage());
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        double width = 0;
        double height = 0;
        width = thePic.getWidth();
        height = thePic.getHeight();

}
```

the error is in this line :
width = thePic.getWidth();

what is the problem ? what should I do with android 5 ?

thanks

Comment: do you have `onRestoreInstance()` and `onSaveInstance()` method in your activity? May be you activity is recreating itself while coming back from Camera Activity.